# problem with writing large data using java nio socket channel

Tags: java, nio

I can sent small data using java nio.

But If I want to send a very large data then my socket channel did not work fine.

```
message = "very large data"+"\n";
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBytes());
int nbytes = channel.write(buf);
```

all the data is sent.

I want to read data from server so i am using BufferedInputStreaReader.readLine();
In this case I am not getting any error also i cannot retrieve any of the data that i have sent

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work fine" ? Do you have an exception ?

Comment: You are going to have to explain what exactly isn't working... Exception, stack trace, something...

Answer (score 1):

```
write()

Returns:
The number of bytes written, possibly zero
```

Write is not guaranteed to write your whole buf.
You need to check how much that was written, and do another write.  (Probably also wait (select) until you can write again.)

You should probably also search for a good java.nio tutorial... 
If you need a simpler api, use the blocking io in java.io instead...